# AWS Amplify doesn't create dynamoDB tables and resets back to old data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I've created few DataStore tables with AWS Amplify. After deploying, I can see the fields of all tables have been changed to different names, that I've used couple of days ago. I've followed the same steps again, deployed, added table data manually and deployed again. I can see the same thing happened again. The names of the fields have been changed and this time the table data is gone. Then I deleted all tables from DynamoDB interface. Followed the same steps. This time, there are no tables on DynamoDB interface, however there are tables visible on Amplify. Gave up after trying many hours. Does this happen due to caching of AWS amplify or is there any way to solve this issue?